# pass a linq query with group by to view [errors out]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I got this in the controller

```
var tobi = (from a in db.Assessments
join u in db.Users on a.rated equals u.user_id
join tm in db.Team_Members on u.user_id equals tm.user_id
join t in db.Teams on tm.team_id equals t.team_id
where (tm.end_date == null || tm.end_date > DateTime.Today)
group new TobiViewModel
{
    teamname = t.name,
    assessed_due = a.assessed_due,
    assessment_id = a.assessment_id,
    rater = a.rater,
    rated = a.rated
}
by new { t.name, a.rated }).ToList();

return View(tobi);
```

But then it doesn't accept it in the view?

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[<>f__AnonymousType10`2[System.String,System.String],Kyubu.ViewModels.TobiViewModel]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Kyubu.ViewModels.TobiViewModel]'.

how should i pass this in the view. Any help would be appreciated
The type in the view is

```
@model IEnumerable<Kyubu.ViewModels.TobiViewModel>
```

Comment: I think when you hover the var it says what the actual type of 'tobi' is? You can then use that type as model in your view (instead of the IEnumerable<TobiViewModel>)

Comment: When you group by in linq you get a IGrouping<T, U> back where T is what you group by (in this case an anonymous type with 2 string properties) and U is what is grouped here TobiViewModel.

Comment: The main problem here is that your key is an anonymous type, so you will not be able to specify it as your model type. If you can chanhe the type of your key with a known type, or with dynamic, then it should be easier to solve your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following in the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<object, Kyubu.ViewModels.TobiViewModel>>
```

Comment: didn't work it Error 7 Using the generic type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<TKey,TElement>' requires 2 type arguments.

Comment: It needed extra bracket on the end.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Works now!